# Changing the title and the description below the collectionView cell When the collection view cell change. Doing this with index path is not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, indexpath

[image: Hope this pic helps descripe the case]I am updating the title and the description with the index path that i get when i cahnge the collection view index, But this is not doing the right things because when i scroll to end and start scrolling back the description and title associated with each cell shows the unintended ones.

```
class IntroPage : BaseViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var pageController: UIPageControl!
@IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

private let reuseIdentifier = "CollectionViewCellIntroScene"

    let collectionViewImages : [UIImage] = [
#imageLiteral(resourceName: "maskGroup30"), 
#imageLiteral(resourceName: "maskGroup34"), 
#imageLiteral(resourceName: "maskGroup33")
]

let collectionViewTitleTexts : [String] = [
    "Track Your Fitness",
    "Win Exciting Deals",
    "Be a Challenge Winner!"
]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "CollectionViewCellIntroScene", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    renderCells()
}

func renderCells() {
    collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
    collectionView.isScrollEnabled = true
    collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(layout, animated: true)
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.delegate = self

}

}
```

Delegate for the Collection View

```
extension IntroPage : UICollectionViewDelegate {
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return collectionViewImages.count
}
}
```

Data Source for Collection View

```
extension IntroPage : UICollectionViewDataSource {

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    pageController?.currentPage = Int(scrollView.contentOffset.x) / Int(scrollView.frame.width)
}

func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    pageController?.currentPage = Int(scrollView.contentOffset.x) / Int(scrollView.frame.width)
}
```

Here when i scroll forward and then backward the title and description shows the wrong outputs

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCellIntroScene

    cell.image.image = collectionViewImages[indexPath.item]
    titleLabel.text = collectionViewTitleTexts[indexPath.item]
    
    return cell
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, did you fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using a common `titleLabel` and `descriptionLabel` and setting the title and description in `cellForItemAt`, which is called when the cell is loaded. Move the following from `IntroPage` to your cell `CollectionViewCellIntroScene` (modify the xib by adding the title and desc labels):

```
@IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!
```

and in `cellForRowAt`:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCellIntroScene
    cell.image.image = collectionViewImages[indexPath.item]
    cell.titleLabel.text = collectionViewTitleTexts[indexPath.item]
    return cell
}
```

Comment: I tried it and yet it didnt work, Knowing that the index of the page controller is correct. When i print in the cellForItemAt the index path this is what i get , at app start --> 0 when i scroll to the next cell it prints 1 and 2 together and when i go to the third cell it prints nothing , when going back am at third cell going to second it prints 0 then when i reach first cell it prints nothing

Comment: That's fine. It's loading the upcoming cell too. That's not your issue. No need to dig in that direction.

Comment: humm, okay but how can i fix this any idea !? i was just trying to give nore details :)

Comment: Are you having the issue with the title and description alone? Is it showing the right image?

Comment: Yes the image is loading correctly, the title is not, knowing that i did not implement the code of the description yet.

Comment: But my XIB cell is designed to hold only the Image, do i need to redesign it in a way that i will hold image + title + desc ?

Comment: Yes exactly. I thought it was clear from the above answer. I've added a note in case it wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have to clean your cells while scrolling
Create separate class for your Cell and use there method prepareForReuse to clean your cells

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    yourLabel.text = ""
}
```

Comment: But my cell only holds the image the other labels are not in the XIB file, my XIB file only holds the image and others are in storyboard